# When I compile my program for Debugging the Lua runs fine but why I compile it for release I get a c0000005 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lua

I'm using LUA for a SDL project. I downloaded the precompiled LIB and DLL file from here (http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/) (lua-5.2_Win32_dll10_lib.zip) and have incorporated it into my project. When I build a debug build the application runs 100% fine. When I set it to release mode and press the Play button in Visual Studio it also runs fine.

BUT if I run the Release file by doubling clicking it in the folder I get the error c0000005 with the lua52.dll.

I'm running MicroSoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

I went through deleting lines till it started working and the lines that causes the error are.

```
void aiBrainmanager::run(string holdData){

int errfunc = 0;
int s;
int s = luaL_loadstring(L, holdData.c_str());

if ( s==0 ) {
    s = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, errfunc);
}
if (errfunc !=0) {

}
if (s !=0) {

    aiBrainmanager::target->stopWorking();
}


}
```

Any idea what setting is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: The information here really isn't enough for someone to guess at what the problem might be.  In a debug build it is likely that many uninitialized variables will be set to 0, where in a release build they will not.  I would check for that first, and also add debug print/log statements around where the problem is so you can see what might be wrong.  You can also use a debugger for this, but debugging optimized code can be difficult if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0xc0000005 is a memory violation. The fact that it works in debug, means a number possible things.

1. Memory is not being initialised or set correctly (in debug it's initialed to 0) so string are terminated for example.
2. Memory requirements are larger than th buffers allow (in debug it could be padded).
3. You code is doing something different in debug than compile (#if etc.)

Looking at your code I would look at:

Why are you checking for error and then not doing anything?????

```
if (errfunc !=0) { 
 // What happens in here??????
}
```

> The [lua_pcall function](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pcall) returns 0 in case of success or one of the
>   following error codes (defined in lua.h):
>
> - LUA_ERRRUN: a runtime error.
> - LUA_ERRMEM: memory allocation error. For such errors, Lua does not    call the error handler function.
> - LUA_ERRERR: error while running the error handler function

I think you'll find you're getting a **LUA_ERRMEM**

Comment: It's been resolved. If you define a pointer in the header of a class (In this case the variable, lua_State *L ) in a debug setting the pointer won't be set to NULL when the Constructors function (In this case aiBrainmanager::aiBrainmanager is called) This triggered some code I wrote to recreate the lua_State function because a error was detected. In release mode the pointer was set to NULL it stopped the lua_State being created at all which was the actual problem. Thank you.